# How to make if not statement in shell (/bin/sh)?

Tags: shell, git

I am using shell to write a git hook file, to check my commit message before commit. I an a total beginner, this is what I have tried:

My `commit-msg` hook file is like below:

```
#!/bin/sh
msg=`head -n 1 $1`


if echo $msg | egrep -qv '(Android-\d{3,4}.{20,})'; then
  echo "[Message Format] Your message is not formatted correctly. Correct message format\n 
    #Ticket Number - Minimum 20 or more Character \n 
    like #Android-123 Bug fixed for login issue"
  exit 1;
fi
```

So whenever I make a commit message like this:

```
git commit -m " #Android-123 I pretty sure this is more than 20 character,but it still failed to commit"
```

So I  pretty sure my commit message is more than 20 character, and the ticket number, but every time I commit it still get the error I set.

I think my logic problem is that I should use `if not echo $msg | egrep -qv '(Android-\d{3,4}.{20,})'`, so I tried:

```
 if ! [[echo $msg | egrep -qv '(Android-\d{3,4}.{20,})']] ; 
 then....
```

But this give me this error:  `.git/hooks/commit-msg: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token !'`

**Question:**

1. What I going wrong that cause failed to commit, even though I make a right commit message?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: i tried(in commit-msg file) exactly this : `if echo " #Android-123 I pretty sure this is more than 20 character,but it still failed to commit" || egrep -qv '(Android-\d{3,4}.{20,})' ; then` ,then `git commit` again,it still give me the same error

Comment: `[Message Format] Your message is not formatted correctly. Correct message format\n
   #Ticket Number - Minimum 20 or more Character \n
   like #Android-123 Bug fixed for login issue`  exactly this error that I set myself

Comment: Note that `[[ ... ]]` syntax 1) is not supported in the plain POSIX shell (it's a `bash`ism; see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3427872/673852)), 2) doesn't do what you thought it did. To group multiple commands you should use `{ echo hello; echo hi; }` instead, or run them in a subshell like `( echo hello; echo hi )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regular expression uses PCRE syntax like `\d`, but `grep -E` (that's what your `egrep` is, but use `grep -E` instead, `egrep` is being deprecated) doesn't understand that. Also, you don't need the parentheses there, you aren't actually capturing anything. If you have GNU `grep`, you can use `grep -P` instead:

```
grep -Pqv 'Android-\d{3,4}.{20,}'
```

If not, you will have to replace `\d` with `[0-9]`:

```
grep -Eqv 'Android-[0-9]{3,4}.{20,}'
```

However, you don't need (or want) to only take the first line of the file, you can just grep the whole file directly. You also don't need to reverse the match (`-v`), that just complicates things.  Here's a simpler, working version of your script, using `if !` to negate the condition:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! grep -E 'Android-[0-9]{3,4}.{20,}' "$1"; then
  printf "[Message Format] Your message is not formatted correctly. Correct message format: 
    #Ticket Number - Minimum 20 or more Character 
    like #Android-123 Bug fixed for login issue\n"
  exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Note that to match on 0123456789, the syntax is `[[:digit:]]` or `[0123456789]`; `[0-9]` matches on a lot more characters in some locales on some systems.

Comment: Your approach wouldn't flag as incorrect a message whose second line matches the pattern, but not the first.

Comment: The error message should probably go on stderr.

Comment: With the GNU or busybox implementations of `grep`, you'd need a `--` after `-E` or better use redirections instead of passing the filename as argument or it wouldn't work for file names that start with `-`.

Comment: Note that POSIX doesn't forbid `grep` implementations to support `\d` as meaning _decimal digit_, as it leaves the behaviour unspecified if one uses it in a regex (outside of bracket expressions). Some implementations like ast-open's `grep` do support it. GNU `grep` doesn't support it yet.

Comment: Note that the regex is functionally equivalent to `Android-[0-9]{3}.{20}'`. The upper bounds are irrelevant here since there's no anchoring on the right. Both would match on `Android-12345678901234567890123`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas this is for a git commit file, there's no reason to protect against `-`. And in my understanding, only one line needs to match. Note how the OP had originally only taken the first line anyway. Fair point about the upper bound, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I'd do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
file="${1?No file specified}"

die() {
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
  exit 1
}

awk '
  BEGIN {ret = !ok}
  /^#Android-[[:digit:]]{3,4}[^[:digit:]].{19}/ {ret = ok}
  {exit}
  END {exit ret}' < "$file" || die \
    '[Message Format] Your message is not formatted correctly. Correct message format:' \
    '#Ticket Number - Minimum 20 or more Character' \
    'like #Android-123 Bug fixed for login issue'
```

(remove the `^` if you don't require the ticket number to be at the start of the line).